# Rails 3 - AJAX Redirect? Pass class from Controller to View for AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's what I'm trying to do...

**Controller**

```
def create
.
.
 if @project.save
  format.js  {  @project }
 end

end
```

**View**

```
window.location = "<%= redirect_to(@project, :notice => 'Project was successfully created.') %>";
```

In Sum,using AJAX to create a project. When the create is done, I want to redirect the user to the project..

This isn't working... How can I pass the project from the controller to the View?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Writing below code on `create.js.erb` is not working.

```
redirect_to(@project, :notice => 'Project was successfully created.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I like:

```
def create
  ...
 if @project.save
   render js: %[window.location.pathname='#{project_path(@project)}']
 end
end
```